# How to use a generic delegate in an interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, delegates

I'm trying to create an interface holding a generic delegate. I then want the classes implementing the interface to decide the actual type method, or preferably even return another delegate.

Below are some code describing what I'm trying to acheive.

```
public delegate void GenericMethod<T>(T arg);
public delegate void StringMethod(string str);
public delegate void ByteMethod(byte bt);

public interface ITest
{
    GenericMethod<T> someMethod;    
}

public class TestA : ITest
{
    public GenericMethod<string> someMethod
    {
         get 
         {
               return stringMethod; //which is of type StringMethod(string str), defined above
         }
    }
}

public class TestB : ITest
{
    public GenericMethod<byte> someMethod
    {
         get 
         {
               return byteMethod; //which is of type ByteMethod(byte bt);, defined above
         }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Or is it impossible to switch delegates in such a manner?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is possible without making the interface generic. The common implementation would be:

```
public interface ITest<T>
{
    GenericMethod<T> someMethod;
}
```

Or, if you want to actually have a non-generic interface, use:

```
public interface ITest
{
    GenericMethod<object> someMethod;
}
```

You can also take a look at two interfaces `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` to see how you can combine both generic and non-generic interfaces. Just implement the non-generic interface explicitly for use when you do not care about the concrete type.

Answer (score 0):

```
public delegate void GenericMethod<T>(T arg);
public delegate void StringMethod(string str);
public delegate void ByteMethod(byte bt);

public interface ITest<T>
{
    GenericMethod<T> someMethod { get; };
}

public class TestA : ITest<string>
{
    public GenericMethod<string> someMethod
    {
        get
        {
            return stringMethod; //which is of type StringMethod(string str), defined above
        }
    }
}

public class TestB : ITest<byte>
{
    public GenericMethod<byte> someMethod
    {
        get
        {
            return byteMethod; //which is of type ByteMethod(byte bt);, defined above
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because of inheritance principles. All, that works in ITest, should work in derived classes/interfaces. That means, if I'm able to use

```
GenericMethod<int> someMethod
```

(look at int) in ITest, I should be able to use it in TestA and TestB. You are trying to ignore this restriction